# Regex limit number of occurrences of alphanumeric chars

Tags: regex

I have some regex that I'm using with Xeger to generate some strings matching a pattern.

Currently I have:

```
Xeger generator = new Xeger("[a-zA-Z]{8,16}[0-9]{1,6}");

string result = generator.Generate();
```

However I'm looking to limit the results to have a maximum of 2 occurrences of any one letter or number. E.g.

> aabbcc11 - passes
>
> **aaa**bc11 - fails
>
> a**bbb**cc11 - fails
>
> aabb112233 - passes
>
> aabbcc**111** - fails
>
> **a**bb**a**cc**a**11 - fails

Whats the cleanest way to do this with regex?

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew C# I'm actually using the .Net port of Xeger (https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare)

Comment: What is the value that `string result` contains? A string of what? I guess a regex like `Regex.IsMatch(result, @"(.)(?:.*\1){2}")` can help you find "bad" items - if they are separate.

Comment: A randomly generated string based on the Regex input, so at the moment its generating an alphanumeric string min 9, max 22 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Regex.IsMatch(result, @"(.)(?:.*\1){2}")` to filter out "bad" candidates:

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
...
string result = generator.Generate();
if (!Regex.IsMatch(result, @"(.)(?:.*\1){2}")) {
    results.Add(result);
}
```

See [pattern demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28%3F%3A.*%5C1%29%7B2%7D&i=aabbcc11%0D%0Aaabb112233%0D%0A%0D%0Aabbbcc11%0D%0Aaaabc11%0D%0Aaabbcc111%0D%0Aabbacca11). Details:

- `(.)` - Group 1 capturing a char other than newline
- `(?:.*\1){2}` - 2 occurrences (`{2}`) of any 0+ chars other than newline (`.*`) and the value captured in Group 1 (`\1`).